# C# Math correct syntax

Tags: c#, math

```
for (int bb = 1; bb <= 24; bb++)
{
    if (x > Math.Exp(Math.Log(2) * (-bb)))
    {
        x = r - Math.Exp(Math.Log(2) * (-bb));
        xbb = 1;
    }
    else
    {
       xbb = 0;
    }
}
```

for the start my r=0.1 after i get my first 'x', I want to inset it into 'r' for the next step. so 'r' looks like previous value of 'x' (`r=x_n-1`).

I know how to do it in MathCad, but have no idea how to do it in C#.

Comment: You should really use more meaningful variable names.

Comment: You're already performing 4 assignment operations in the code that you have, so why is this one any different?

Comment: Why can't you just put "r = x" in the appropriate place in the code?

Comment: Your question isn't about math. Your title and tags mean this question isn't going to help anyone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need just something like:

```
if (x > Math.Exp(Math.Log(2) * (-bb)))
{
    x = r - Math.Exp(Math.Log(2) * (-bb));
    xbb = 1;
    r = x;
}
```

So in the next iteration `r` will hold "previous" value of `x`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're essentially just computing the binary representation of x.  `Math.Exp( Math.Log(2) * -bb )` is a rather long-winded way of just writing `Math.Pow(2, -bb)`.  You don't need to compute it like that, either.  Here's how I'd do it (assuming your variables are `double`):

```
double x = r;
double pow = 0.5;
for( int i = 0; i < 24; ++i )
{
    int xbb = 0;
    if( x > pow )
    {
        x -= pow;
        xbb = 1;
    }

    pow /= 2;
}
```